# Many to Many Relation - Access column values

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a `User` model (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`) and a `Like` model (`id`, `to_user_id`, `isLiked`), having a many to many relations.

I want to extract all the ids of a Like by a user, namely:

1) `$user->likes`
It gives me all the Like model instances of the user, perfect!

2) But now I want only to extract the "to-user_id" from the instances. Doing something like this does not work:

```
$user->likes->to_user_id
```

Can you help me find the proper way?

Thanks a mil! I've been struggling for hours now already...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `->pluck()` collection method to achieve this:

```
$user->likes->pluck('to_user_id')->all();
```

`$user->likes` returns all `likes` as a collection, which will give you access to [collection methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections).

`->pluck()` will return a specified key/value. You then use `->all()` to return all as an `array`.

Comment: Awesome answer, perfect! And I love the fact that you give me the way to better understand collection methods! Thanks a mil buddy! :)
After trying your solution, I think the "all()" is not necessary if I'm not mistaken..

Comment: @Laurent Welcome. Collection methods are very powerful, give them a look up.